# Unhandled Promise Rejection when throwing error

Tags: javascript, tdd, sinon, koa

I've written a test to check my function for error catching. When the function errors, `next()` will be called. I would like to rewrite it so the function throws an error and I can use `spy.should.have.thrown(error)`. However, when I try to throw an error, I keep getting warnings:

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: catch me`

`DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code`

**The test:**

```
const chai = require('chai');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const sinonChai = require('sinon-chai');
chai.should();
chai.use(sinonChai);

const mockStory = {};
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');

//creates mock model functions to replace original model functions in controller
const Story = proxyquire('../controller/controller',
  { '../model/model' : mockStory}
);

describe('Story should be created', () => {

  const ctx = {request: {body:'foo'}};

  it ('createStory should catch errors from model', async () => {
    const foo = ctx.request.body;
    mockStory.createStory = (foo) => {
      throw new Error('error');
    };
    const next = sinon.spy();
    const res = Story.createStory(ctx, next);
    next.should.have.been.called;
  });

});
```

**The function on the controller being tested:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Story = require('../model/model');
const Console = console;

const createStory = async (ctx, next) => {
  try {
    const createdStory = await Story.createStory(ctx.request.body);
    ctx.status = 200;
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
    //gives unhandled promise rejection warning...
    throw new Error('catch me')
  }
};

module.exports = {
  createStory,
};
```

Can someone please tell me how I can throw an error and test for that error?

Comment: What is the purpose of `throw new Error('catch me')`?

Comment: I want it to throw an error so I can test the error handling... otherwise, right now, it doesn't serve any other purpose...

Comment: The code does handle the error from `await Story.createStory(ctx.request.body)` at `catch(){}`. The code also creates a new `Error` at `catch(){}` for no apparent reason.

Comment: I think you should be calling `createStory` for the controller in your test _(wherever that is)_ and not `Story.createStory`. Also `Story.createStory` should be the mocked function not the controller's `createStory`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the controller returning a promise. Using the chai-as-promised library solved the error.

```js
//controller.js
const createStory = async (ctx, next) => {
  try {
    const createdStory = await Story.createStory(ctx.request.body);
    ctx.status = 200;
  } catch (error) {
    ctx.throw('Could not create story!');
  }
};

//tests.js

const chai = require('chai');
var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
chai.should();

const mockStoryModel = {};
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');

const StoriesController = proxyquire('../controller/controller',
  { '../model/model' : mockStoryModel}
);

describe('Story', () => {

  const ctx = {request: {body:'foo'}};

  it ('createStory should catch errors from model', async () => {
    const foo = ctx.request.body;
    mockStory.createStory = (foo) => {
      throw new Error('error');
    };
    Story.createStory().should.be.rejected;
  });

});
```